# What does the odds-ratio significance tells us?

Tags: logistic, odds-ratio

I started to work with Logit very recently and I think I fail to understand some of its subtleties.

For instance, I have a dataset (n=150) for which I perform a Logit Reg. The dependent variable is 1 if the individual is married, 0 else :

| Name | Coef | Odd-Ratio | p-value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| constant | -1.3208 | 0.26 | 0.0649 |
| Age (continuous) | -0.1386 | 0.32 | 0.025 |
| Employed? (0=False, 1=True) | -1.1029 | 0.33 | 0.261 |
| Score_Academic (ordinal) | 0.0488 | 1.04 | 0.37 |

So if I understood odds-ratio correctly, it indicates that an one-point increase in Age would in turn reduce the odds of getting from 0 to 1 to 0.26, or 26%. Similarly, the fact of being Employed would reduce the odds to 33% to get from an outcome to another (0 to 1), whereas a one-point increase in Score_Academic would yields a 4% increase in the odds.

My problem lies on the significance of those values. As shown on the Table, the odds-ratio (and coefficients) of both Age and Employment are really close, yet only one between the twos is significant to the 0.05 level. Why is it the case? Is it due to the fact that odds of an outcome for a given variable is only due to checking for this variable, holding the other variables constant? Is it due to the continuous nature of the variable? I'm a bit lost on this, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hm. The [odds ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio) compares two specific situations. For Employed, that is easy: it's the odds for someone employed to be married, divided by the odds for someone unemployed to be married. That also works out with the coefficient estimate: $\exp(-1.1029)=0.33$. ...

Comment: ...  For Age, it's not so obvious that the comparison is between someone aged $n$ years and someone aged $n+1$ years. And the math does not work out, either: $\exp( -0.1386)=0.87$. It looks like the OR for age compares two people $\log(0.32)/( -0.1386)=8.22$ years apart, which may be a reasonable number for the age spread in your dataset, maybe the Age IQR. So: can you check what assumptions are made on the calculation of the ORs?

Comment: Finally, note that p-values are usually not calculated for ORs (as we see, ORs can depend on continuous predictors), but for coefficient estimates. And those are indeed quite different between Age and Employed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For the Age, its standard deviation in my dataset is 9.42 so if I understood correctly, it means that for one increase of 9.42 years between two persons, there would be a 32% decrease in the odds?

Comment: As for assumptions, do you mean for instance checking for mulitcolinearity (which is not a problem, I computed the VIFs and they were quite low), or something else?

Comment: It does not look like the OR is calculated for a difference of one standard deviation in Age, because $\exp(-0.1386*9.42)=0.27$, not $0.32$, so it must be something else. (And the *decrease* in odds would be $1-0.32=68\%$.) By "assumptions" I meant checking how your software calculates ORs for continuous predictors. It apparently does not use the SD in the predictor, but something else. Best to check the documentation.